# Roof with different pitch and eave height

Tags: vector, geometry, cluster-computing, revit-api

I'm trying to create the roof footprint with only line where each line is associated with slope and eave height. I tried some of the CAD software but it didn't fulfill all requirements with example at my end. I also tried Straight skeleton algorithm but couldn't find any workround withit. Is there any logic or any algorithm which will help me create roof[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roof Creation with Eave Heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924102/roof-creation-with-eave-heights)

Comment: Please don't post the same question repeatedly. If you want to draw attention to your original post, you can edit it or (after more time has passed) offer a bounty, but reposting the same question will just result in it being closed.